# Get data from related tables in SQL database using vb.net DataRow class

Tags: database, vb.net, datarow

I have relational tables like this

Orders: (id, customerId(FK), productId(FK), date)

Customers: (id(PK), name, surname)

Products: (id(PK), name, price)

in Orders table, customerId and productId have foreign keys

And my vb codes like this;

```
dim da as New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from Orders", conn)

dim ds as New DataSet

da.fill(ds, vt)

For each dr as DataRow in ds.Tables(vt).rows
    orderId = dr("id")
    orderDate = dr("date")
    ordererName = 'I want to see customer name here
    ordererSurname = 'I want to see customer surname here
    productName = 'I want to see product name here
    .
    .
    .
Next
```

above code snippet is an example to explain mu question, actual codes are different. As you can see, i want to get data from related tables by using relational databases

Comment: Use joins in your query

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b I will need to run more than one SQL query with the joins method. And maybe I will create a different datatable for each select query. Could there be a simpler method instead? for example like this; customerName = dr("customerId.name")

Comment: @AndrewMorton It's more useful for me to solve this in vb. If there is a way

Comment: @ilkaykurt Using joins in the SQL you would get the data from each database table combinbed into one datatable in your program, which appears to be what you asked for.

Comment: @ilkaykurt Something like: `SELECT ord.id AS 'id', ord.date AS 'date', C.name AS 'name', C.surname AS 'surname', P.name AS 'prodName'
FROM Orders AS ord
JOIN Customers AS C
ON C.id = ord.customerId
JOIN Products AS P
ON P.id = ord.productId`

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you, this seems to solve my problem, but I have 45 columns in total and defining a different variable for each column in the select query will lengthen the command line considerably. When I use * in the select query, the variables of the incoming columns are automatically defined and those with the same name are appended with a number. Thus, it becomes difficult to find which one is the column name I want. Do you know a way to get around this? ![screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/gJ61rHm/Ads-z.jpg)

Comment: These are columns with the same name from different tables. ![edited screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/LYJsJfx/Ads-z.jpg)

Comment: @ilkaykurt Sometimes you just have to type a lot. You can format it however you like because strings can go over more than one line in VB.NET. You get to choose the name of the column with the parts like `ord.id AS 'id'` - it could have been `longTableName.reallyLongColumnName AS 'x'` to use it as column name "x" in the VB part. Also, it might be better to make it as a *stored procedure*.